# AnimatedVisibility & SwipeToDismiss Enter Animation does not trigger - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Okay so I've been trying to implement **swipe to delete** function in my app. Whenever I swipe one of the items from the list I'm able to see a RedBackground behind and everything works fine. Also the swipe **animation** when I delete an item is triggered successfully. (Even though I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use delay for that? I can't think of any other way to do it).
But the **enter animation** when I add an item to the database/list is not working, and I'm not sure why. Here's the code of my Lazy Column

```
@Composable
fun DisplayTasks(
    tasks: List<ToDoTask>,
    onSwipeToDelete: (Action, ToDoTask) -> Unit,
    navigateToTaskScreen: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(
            items = tasks,
            key = { task ->
                task.id
            }
        ) { task ->
            val dismissState = rememberDismissState()
            val dismissDirection = dismissState.dismissDirection
            val isDismissed = dismissState.isDismissed(DismissDirection.EndToStart)

            if (isDismissed && dismissDirection == DismissDirection.EndToStart
            ) {
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
                scope.launch {
                    delay(300)
                    onSwipeToDelete(Action.DELETE, task)
                }
            }

            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = !isDismissed,
                exit = shrinkVertically(
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 300,
                    )
                ),
                enter = expandVertically(
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 300
                    )
                )
            ) {
                SwipeToDismiss(
                    state = dismissState,
                    directions = setOf(DismissDirection.EndToStart),
                    dismissThresholds = { FractionalThreshold(0.2f) },
                    background = { RedBackground() },
                    dismissContent = {
                        LazyColumnItem(
                            toDoTask = task,
                            navigateToTaskScreen = navigateToTaskScreen
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't perform any state changing actions inside composable. Instead use one of side effects, usually `LaunchedEffect(key) { }`: content of the block will be called on the first render and each time key is different from the last render. Also inside you're already in a coroutine scope, so no need to launch it. Check out more about side-effects in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

Item animation in the list is [not yet supported](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#item-animations). It's as simple as adding `AnimatedVisibility` to the items.

When compose firstly sees `AnimatedVisibility` in the compose tree, it draws(or not draws) it without animation.

And when on next recomposition `visible` is different from the last render time, it animates.

So to make it work as you wish you can do the following:

1. Add `itemAppeared` state value, which will make item in the list initially hidden, and using side effect make it visible right after render
2. Add `columnAppeared` which will prevent initial appearance animation - without it when screen renders all items will appear animatedly too

```
@Composable
fun DisplayTasks(
    tasks: List<ToDoTask>,
    onSwipeToDelete: (Action, ToDoTask) -> Unit,
) {
    var columnAppeared by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        columnAppeared = true
    }
    LazyColumn {
        items(
            items = tasks,
            key = { task ->
                task.id
            }
        ) { task ->
            val dismissState = rememberDismissState()
            val dismissDirection = dismissState.dismissDirection
            val isDismissed = dismissState.isDismissed(DismissDirection.EndToStart)
            if (isDismissed && dismissDirection == DismissDirection.EndToStart
            ) {
                LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    delay(300)
                    onSwipeToDelete(Action.DELETE, task)
                }
            }

            var itemAppeared by remember { mutableStateOf(!columnAppeared) }
            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                itemAppeared = true
            }
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = itemAppeared && !isDismissed,
                exit = shrinkVertically(
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 300,
                    )
                ),
                enter = expandVertically(
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 300
                    )
                )
            ) {
                SwipeToDismiss(
                    state = dismissState,
                    directions = setOf(DismissDirection.EndToStart),
                    dismissThresholds = { FractionalThreshold(0.2f) },
                    background = {
                        Box(
                            Modifier
                                .background(Color.Red)
                                .fillMaxSize()
                        )
                    },
                    dismissContent = {
                        Text(task.id)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Philip! It worked but with one modification, instead of passing Unit to LaunchedEffect, I needed to pass true as a key1 parameter instead.

Comment: @Hassa if you're passing static value `true` it should work totally the same as with `Unit`

Comment: I've tried with Unit, but this line of code wasn't triggering:
onSwipeToDelete(Action.DELETE, task)

Comment: @TarasMykhalchuk You're welcome. Since this answer some system animation API become available, you can check example in [this repo](https://github.com/KlassenKonstantin/LazyListAnimations/blob/main/app/src/main/java/de/apuri/lazylistanimations/MainActivity.kt) made by a maintainer.

Comment: Checkout this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72537949/jetpack-compose-lazy-column-insertion-and-deletion-animations-with-multiple-item/72537950#72537950