# How to get animations when new item is added to LazyColumn?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

How, to attain animation like we get in DiffUtil RecyclerView when new items are added to the list?

I've a LazyColumn with multiple items as composables. Each composable are different.
My code looks like this:

```
LazyColumn{
    item{
        ChipGroup()
    }
    viewModel.list.forEach{
        item{
            ListItem()
        }
    }
    item{
        ContinueButton()
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

So, How to attain a simple animation like we get as default in DiffUtil RecyclerView when each time viewModel.list gets a new item added?

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68928544/3585796)

Comment: when scrolling ,animation is playing because launched effect is triggering when item comes to foreground. is there any way to solve this? thanks!

Comment: Oh yes, I think, as I said in that reply, you should wait for official support. You could try tracking added items with `LaunchedEffect` + `remember`, but if it were that easy to implement, I think it would already be official=)

Comment: Checkout this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72537949/jetpack-compose-lazy-column-insertion-and-deletion-animations-with-multiple-item/72537950#72537950